# hasManyThrough for 4 tables

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Sorry, if the question already exists... Unluckily, I don't know how to do it.

In fact, I have 4 tables

[image]

I have 2 goals, the first is to retrieve in my table `Feedback`, the `date_seance` via my table `Training`. So, here I work on 3 tables.

I succeeded to join.

[image]

In my Model `Feedback` I have this

```
public function students(){

    return $this->belongsTo('App\Student', 'fk_student');
    }

    public function feedbacks()
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough(
            'App\Feedback',
            'App\Student',
            'fk_training', 
            'fk_student',
            'id', 
            'id' 
        );
    }
```

And in my file `index.blade` I have this:

```
 <th>Direction</th>
 <th>Summarized</th>
 <th>Name</th>
 <th>Firstname</th>
 <th>Date of seance</th>
 <th>Trainer</th>
 </tr>
 </thead>

 @foreach($feedbacks as $feedback)
 <tr>
  <td> {{$feedback->direction}}</td>
  <td> {{$feedback->summarized}}</td>
  <td> {{$feedback->students->name}}</td>  
  <td> {{$feedback->students->firstname}}</td>  
  <td> {{$feedback->students()->first()->training()->first()->date_seance->format('d/m/Y')}}</td>
```

My problem now is to know how Can I join the `name of the trainer` in my table `feedback`?

I am really stuck.

Can I do it via my function feedbacks() in my model feedback?

I thank you for your precious help.

Comment: Take a look here: https://github.com/staudenmeir/eloquent-has-many-deep

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `Training` model has a relationship to `Trainer` (hasOne?), you should be able to call that method directly.

`$feedback->students()->first()->training()->first()->trainer`